# Installers Deploying SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 on 64-bit machines

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, 64-bit, setup-deployment

I'm running VS2010 SP1.

We want to create a project using SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2.

I just downloaded this from Microsoft, and it placed two installers in my folder (a 32 and a 64-bit version) along with an instructional text file.

For a 64-bit PC like I am on, the text file had me install the 32-bit version first, then install the 64-bit version.

If we create an application that is going to be deployed to others in other companies, will a standard VS Setup and Deploy project install both versions in the correct order on the target 64-bit machines?

I don't want to spend months developing this new product only to find in the end that it will not deploy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup the Custom Actions of your Setup and Deployment project (or installer project). In code you can ensure that one is installed first and then the other....

Comment: So, on the `BeforeInstall`, I should call `msiexec` with both files, check that they installed correctly before calling the next, then carry on to my installation? {ew!} What if it's already installed? A corrupt install? I understand where you're going with this, but that sounds like a nasty solution.

Comment: Well, Yes and no. In theory you custom actions take over the install. What happens is you detect if the prerequisites exist. The framework will do this for the Framework version (and  will install the required .NET framework if the user's machine doesn't have it). However, I dont think it can detect installed software. In short, you have to write yourself the "custom" software detection using C# WMI/Registry, and maybe WSCript/Powershell scripts etc... Once you know if SQL Compact is installed and what version, then you either skip the installation, check update version, or do a full install.

Comment: If you could point me to something that describes how to determine what version of SQL CE is installed, I'm done here and won't have to post that related question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923218/detecting-if-sql-server-compact-edition-3-5-sp2-x64-is-installed